# /usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/default/locale: UTF-8: not found dpkg

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, locale

I am a linux beginner. when I install any software in Ubuntu16.04,I come across the same error. For example,when I install smplayer(`sudo apt-get install smplayer`) ,then I come across the error below:

```
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/default/locale: UTF-8: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing: install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Below are the outputs of `locale` and `ls -ld /etc/default/locale`

```
robert@robert-ThinkPad:~$ locale
LANG=zh_CN.\ UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_NAME="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_CN. UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

robert@robert-ThinkPad:~$ ls -ld /etc/default/locale
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 76 2月  22  2017 /etc/default/locale
```

[file locale seems werid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K02wj.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When did the problem started?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `locale` and `ls -ld /etc/default/locale`? Please use the `{}` button in the editor toolbar to format code and command output listings. Thanks.

Comment: Something must be wrong with the file locale.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the `/etc/default/locale` with

```
LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="zh_CN:en"
```

and then the probelm was solved